# A Process does not list on x64dbg attach list

Tags: x64dbg, crackme, windows-10

I'm learning RE with x64dbg on Windows10.
It does not list a process in the running process list that I want to attach.
The Process is running 32-bit crackme application for learning.

It was created by eagle0wl.

http://www.mysys.org/eagle0wl/

Why x64dbg does not list process?
I have checked that x64dbg on privilege permission and windows Smart Screen is disabled and so on.

I have no idea why the process does not list as an attached process.

Windows 10 20H2

Comment: I have the 64-bit version running and also does not see the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x64dbg comes in two versions, 32 and 64 bits.

[image]

You need to run the 32-bit version of x64dbg to detect a 32-bit application.

Comment: It does not need something additional operation?

Comment: Not sure if I got what you're trying to say. 
Generally, you just need to get into the `x32` folder, and execute the debugger executable from there, and then hopefully you will be able to find your 32-bit app.

Comment: Eventually I found x32dbg in x64dbg installation directory!

Comment: That's nice, did you try it and did it work?

Comment: It works and It can attach 32bit process

Comment: Awesome, maybe you should mark the answer?